# Conditional expectation probability question

Tags: probability

In my problem, $Y$~$Bin(4,p)$ and the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$ Is $Poi(y)$. I have to work out $E(X|Y=y)$ and then use the formula $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$ to find $E(X)$.

For $E(X|Y=y)$ I have $4p$ since $X|Y=y$ is the poison with a mean of $4p$. However this is all I know and I am not sure how to use this to solve the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\mid Y=y\sim \mathrm{po}(y)$, then ${\rm E}[X\mid Y=y]=y$ and not $4p$. For the latter part use that if $\varphi(y)={\rm E}[X\mid Y=y]$ then ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]=\varphi(Y)$.

Comment: How do I calculate the first part? I presume I have to use $\sum x \cdot f(x|y)$?

Comment: @James: Don't you know that mean of a $\mathrm{po}(\lambda)$-distributed variable is just $\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry I kept having it in my head that the mean was $4p$ for some reason!

Comment: So the latter part is $4p$?

Comment: Indeed @James. ${}$